# Convert a single entity Framework object to dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have a following problem. I have a class in the entity framework model that has properties e.g.:

```
class Company{
    public string Name {get; set};
    public string Address {get; set};
    public string Email{get; set};
    public string WebSite {get; set};
}
```

I have configuration in database that defines whether or not some field should be shown or not e.g:

- Name: show
- Address: show
- Email: hide
- Website: hide

This is dynamic and all fields are referenced by name.

When I display object in view. It would be nice to convert somehow a single object to some dictionary where key will be property name and value will be property value so I can check for every field by name whether it should be shown or not (maybe in some for-each loop) e.g.:

CompanyDetails.cshtml

```
<h2>Company Details</h2>
@foreach(var property in modelDictionary.Keys){

    @if(IsVisible(property))
        @Html.Raw( modelDictionary[property] )
}
```

What is the best way to convert a single object from entity framework model to dictionary of properties? Should I convert it from object to dictionary in the controller action or use model metadata somehow in the view?

I can use reflection on the Company class and find all properties in the class so I can populate dictionary, but this looks like too old-school solution, so I wander is there any better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm kind of confused what you are trying to accomplish and why. Why don't you just not show certain field in the view. OR, add an attribute to your model fields that determine whether they can be shown or not (but I think my first suggestion is easier/makes more sense)?

Comment: I want to avoid repeating adding conditions like a following: @if(IsVisible("Name")) <div>@Html.Raw(model.Name)</div> @if(IsVisible("Address")) <div>@Html.Raw(model.Address)</div> etc. Imagine that you have lot of fields that should be surrounded with the same if condition. In the model I'm returning all fields using something like  c = companies.Where(company=>company.ID == parID); I had a similar earlier code with DataSet where I have referenced cells with column names in a single foreach loop. Although it was a DataSet it was elegant solution, so I would like to do something similar here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `RouteValueDictionary` which allows you to convert an object into a dictionary:

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string WebSite { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new Company
        {
            Address = "some address",
            Email = "some email",
            Name = "some name",
            WebSite = "some website"
        };
        return View(new RouteValueDictionary(model));
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model RouteValueDictionary

<h2>Company Details</h2>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (IsVisible(item.Key))
    {
        <div>@item.Value</div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an indexer on your entity and map that trough reflection to one of the properties in your entity.

Something like:

```
class Entity
{
    public bool this[int index] 
    {
        get 
        {
           // Select all properties, order by name and return the property index
        }
   }

    public bool this[string name] 
    {
        get 
        {
           // Select all properties and return the correct one.
        }
   }
}
```